# Java runtime vacuumdb

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to run vaccum db from java runtime.  Same  syntax I ran in the command tool and it works but running from java it doesnt:

```
final String cmd = "vacuumdb, -d wsemp0408, -v, -z;";

    try {
        System.out.println("ABC BACKUP START");
        java.lang.Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
        java.lang.Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
        System.out.println("ABC BACKUP END");
    }
```

Getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "vacuumdb,": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:328)
at accelteam.sop.backup.DBBackup.start(DBBackup.java:35)
at accelteam.sop.Sop.run(Sop.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
... 5 more
```

Anyone encountered this before?

Adding the full path still shows error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/vacuumdb,": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I created a exe jar used root and chmod 777 the file hoping its permission issue but still the same

Comment: fully path the vacuumdb executable

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding the full path and removing the `,`

```
final String cmd = "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/vacuumdb -d wsemp0408 -v -z";
```

This runs correctly.